# Запутался в выводе на экран сведений из массива

Tags: c#

Запутался в выводе на экран сведений из массива.
**Вот условие задачи.**

Создать базовый класс Plain (самолёт), содержащий поля: тип самолёта, количество пассажиров. Создать производный класс Flight (рейс), содержащий дополнительные поля: номер рейса, название пункта назначения. Описать методы для вывода на экран сведений об объекте, получения и установки значений некоторых полей. Организовать вывод на экран сведений из массива обо всех самолётах, вылетающих в пункт назначения, введённый с клавиатуры (если таких самолётов нет, то вывести соответствующее сообщение).

**А вот код моей незаконченной программы, не знаю что дальше делать, помогите пожалуйста , только учусь**

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApplication2
  {
    class Flight : Plain // производный класс 
  {
    int flight_number; // номер рейса
    string destination; // пункт назначения

     public Fight(int flight_number, string destination)
      : base()  // конструктор для рейса
    {
      this.flight_number = 0;
      this.destination = "Nikuda";
    }

     override public void Show() // метод для вывода информации на экран
  {
    base.Show();
    Console.WriteLine("Номер рейса:" + flight_number);

    Console.WriteLine("Пункт назначения: " + destination);

  }

 public int Flight
 {
     get
     {
       return flight_number;
     }
   set
   {
       flight_number = value;
   }
 }
   public string Destination
  {
     get
    {
       return destination;
    }
     set
    {
       destination = value;
    }
     }
   }
 }
  /************************************/
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApplication2
 {
    class Plain // базовый класс
  {
    string type_of_aircraft;
     int quantity;

    public Plain() // конструктор по умолчанию
   {
      this.type_of_aircraft = "Пассажирский";
      this.quantity = 0;
   }

   public Plain(string type_of_aircraft, int quantity)
  {
     this.type_of_aircraft = type_of_aircraft;
     this.quantity = quantity;
  }
 virtual public void Show()// метод для вывода информации на экран
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Тип самолета: \n" + type_of_aircraft );
     Console.WriteLine("Пассажиры: \n" + quantity);
  }

  public string Type
  {
      get
    {
        return type_of_aircraft;
    }
    set
    {
        type_of_aircraft = value;
     }
   }
  public int Quantity
 {
     get
    {
        return quantity;
    }
   set
   {
         quantity = value;
    }
   }
  }
 }
  /*********************************/
    namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  public class ConvertPlaneTypeToStringException : Exception
 {
    public ConvertPlaneTypeToStringException(string message) : base(message)
   {
   }
}
  enum plane_type
 {
     big,
     small
}
    class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      List<Flight> flights = new List<Flight>();
      Console.WriteLine("Enter number of flights,you want to create");

     string line = Console.ReadLine();
     int numberOfFlights = int.Parse(line);

      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFlights; i++)
     {
         Flight f = new Flight();
         flights.Add(f);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of flights,you want to edit");
    line = Console.ReadLine();
    numberOfFlights = int.Parse(line);
```

Comment: проблема то в чем?

Comment: Не знаю как информацию выводить,  а именно  "обо всех самолётах, вылетающих в пункт назначения, введённый с клавиатуры (если таких самолётов нет, то вывести соответствующее сообщение)."

Comment: вы не знаете как вывести информацию или не знаете как найти эти самолеты или не знаете как считать ввод юзера для поиска самолетов?

Comment: я не знаю как найти эти самолеты, и как считать ввод юзера для поиска самолетов

Comment: что это? `this.flight_number = 0; this.destination = "Nikuda";` У вас все перелеты с одним и тем же номером? С одним и тем же местом назначения? С какими данными ваша коллекция самолетов должна создаваться? Пользователь её вводит? Или вы её сами заполнять должны?

Comment: считывание ввода юзера у вас уже есть в коде `string line = Console.ReadLine();`, считывание пункта назначения вы можете сделать точно так же

Comment: this.flight_number = 0; this.destination = "Nikuda" это у меня конструктор по умолчанию

Comment: Мне нужно что бы выводилась вся информация о самолетах,  вот этого я не понимаю как организовать , то есть юзер вводит какие то данные которые ему нужны, и программа должна ему показать всю информацию о рейсах

Comment: конструктор по умолчанию - это конструктор без параметров, а у вас в классе `Flight` такого нет, но вы его как то вызываете здесь `Flight f = new Flight();`, что означает, что ваш код в принципе не компилируется.

Comment: для того, чтобы выводить информацию о самолетах, надо сначала, чтобы эжта информация сначала в памяти компьютера как то появилась. Откуда ваша программа должна взять информацию о самолетах? Тот код, что вы показываете, он просто не запустится, потому о нем пока даже речи не идет.

Comment: Написать столько сложного кода и запутаться в простых вещах... выглядит так, как будто этот код писал кто-то другой. В любом случае как только у вас будет нормальная коллекция с рейсами, вам нужно будет только запросить у пользователя строку куда летит рейс. А дальше в цикле по коллекции вывести только ту информацию самолетов, у которых будет destination равен введенному пользователем значению.

Comment: Но в любом случае сначала надо создать коллекцию нормально и исправить все ошибки. В том числе бедный полет`Flight`, у которого в конструкторе на борту возникла драка `Fight`.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, а то что "Код писал кто-то другой" это нам в методичке дали в колледже ничего не объяснив... поэтому много вопросов у меня

Comment: @Александр данное сообщество создано для помощи друг другу, но не для бездумного использования. Поэтому не сочтите за грубость, но к подобным вопросам тут относятся настороженно. Может прямое решение вы не получите, но советы и помощь в процессе, это пожалуйста.

Comment: Поэтому если хотите, то скопируйте ваш код в VisualStudio и попробуйте его хотя бы запустить. Сначала перепечатал класс Plain, потом класс Flight, [посмотрите как работает наследование](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.7.php). Потом перейдите к заполнению коллекции с данными, которые ввел пользователь и т.д. постепенно построив приложение и исправляя ошибки. Как только появятся конкретные сформировавшиеся вопросы в процессе решения, то милости просим сюда. Может вам повезет и кто-то увидев ваши попытки думать даже даст полное объяснение от и до.

Comment: Ну и да, можно почитать всякие туториалы, к примеру прочитав 3 главы с того сайта, который я скинул, вопросов и проблем у вас станет на порядок меньше. Хотя у студентов порой со временем туго.

Answer (score 1):

[image: пример работы]

Создадим необходимые классы

```
class Plane
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Seats { get; set; }

    //ctor
    public Plane(string type, int seats)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(type));
        if (seats <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(seats));

        Type = type;
        Seats = seats;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Самолет: {Type}, посадочных мест: {Seats}";
    }
}

class Flight : Plane
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }

    //ctor
    public Flight(string type, int seats, string number, string destination)
        : base(type, seats)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(number));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(destination));

        Number = number;
        Destination = destination;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + $"; Рейс: {Number}, пункт назначения: {Destination}";
    }
}
```

Теперь создадим класс с данными для нашей программы

```
class DataContext
{
    private List<Flight> _flights;

    //ctor
    public DataContext()
    {
        _flights = new List<Flight>
        {
            new Flight("Sukhoi Superjet 100", 98, "A4-304", "Москва"),
            new Flight("Airbus A319", 116, "SU-6315", "Москва"),
            new Flight("Boeing 737-800", 186, "DP-509", "Москва"),
            new Flight("Airbus A319", 116, "SU-6317", "Краснодар"),
            new Flight("Sukhoi Superjet 100", 98, "A4-306", "Краснодар"),
            new Flight("Boeing 737-800", 186, "DP-204", "Сочи"),
            new Flight("Airbus A320-100/200", 192, "5N-6701", "Симферополь"),
            new Flight("EMBRAER EMB 190", 98, "U6-511", "Симферополь"),
            new Flight("Airbus A319", 116, "SU-6895", "Симферополь"),
            new Flight("Airbus A319", 116, "SU-6282", "Владивосток"),
            new Flight("EMBRAER EMB 190", 98, "N4-198", "Владивосток"),
            new Flight("Boeing 777-300",  330, "SU-6281", "Владивосток"),
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Поиск рейсов по назначению
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="destination">город назначения</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Flight> GetFlightsByDestination(string destination)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(destination));

        return _flights.Where(f => f.Destination.Equals(destination))
                       .ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Вывод списка доступных городов (назначения)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> GetListDestinations()
    {
        return _flights.Select(f => f.Destination)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToList();
    }
}
```

как вы заметили, здесь еще есть методы для извлечения данных в нужном формате.

Далее идет реализация польз.интерфейса нашей программы. Для начала нам понадобится класс
пункта меню

```
class MenuItem
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public bool IsTerminal { get; private set; }
    public Command Command { get; private set; }

    //ctor
    public MenuItem(string title, bool isTerminal, Command command)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(title));

        Title = title;
        IsTerminal = isTerminal;
        Command = command ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));
    }

    public static MenuItem CreateTerminal(string title)
    {
        return new MenuItem(title, true, new DoNothingCommand());
    }

    public static MenuItem CreateCommon(string title, Command command)
    {
        return new MenuItem(title, false, command);
    }

    internal void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Title);
    }
}
```

Каждому пункту меню соответствует нужный класс команды. Вот абстракция

```
abstract class Command
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}
```

Вот пример уже нужной реализации

```
class DestinationFlightsCommand : Command
{
    private readonly DataContext _data;

    //ctor
    public DestinationFlightsCommand(DataContext data)
    {
        _data = data ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите город назначения:");

        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var flights = _data.GetFlightsByDestination(input);

        if (flights.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Извините, на данное направление рейсов нет!");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Возможные варианты рейсов:");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

        flights.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
    }
}
```

Все это объединяет класс польз.интерфейса

```
class UserInterface
{
    //ссылка на сервис данных
    private readonly DataContext _data;
    //пункты меню
    private IEnumerable<MenuItem> _menuItems;
    //команда из выбранного пункта меню
    private Command _command;

    //ctor
    public UserInterface(DataContext data)
    {
        _data = data ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

        //заполняем меню
        _menuItems = new MenuItem[]
        {
            MenuItem.CreateCommon("города", new DestinationsCommand(_data)),
            MenuItem.CreateCommon("куда", new DestinationFlightsCommand(_data)),
            MenuItem.CreateTerminal("выход"),
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение меню, выбор пункта меню
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal bool ReadCommand()
    {
        //отображаем меню
        ShowMenu();

        //получаем польз. ввод
        MenuItem selectedMenuItem = SelectMenuItem();
        //если пользователь ошибся с меню
        if (selectedMenuItem == null)
        {
            _command = new DoNothingCommand();
            return true;
        }

        //если выход
        if (selectedMenuItem.IsTerminal)
            return false;

        //если выбран пункт меню
        _command = selectedMenuItem.Command;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отображение списка меню
    /// </summary>
    private void ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Наберите нужную команду:");
        Console.WriteLine();

        //проходим по списку и отображаем все пункты меню
        foreach (MenuItem menuItem in _menuItems)
            menuItem.Display();

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение польз.ввода и выбор пункта меню
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private MenuItem SelectMenuItem()
    {
        //ждем польз. ввод
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        //пытаем найти нужный пункт меню
        return _menuItems.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Title.Equals(input));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Выполнение команды из выбранного пункта меню
    /// </summary>
    internal void ExecuteCommand()
    {
        //если пользователь ошибся с меню
        if (_command is DoNothingCommand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Неверная команда!");
        }
        else
        {
            //иначе выполняем команду
            _command.Execute();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Нажмите ВВОД для продолжения...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Ну, а точка запуска такая

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserInterface ui = new UserInterface(new DataContext());

        while (ui.ReadCommand())
        {
            ui.ExecuteCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

Весь пример лежит [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/ConsoleAppFlights)

Comment: А вот и медвежья услуга всё-таки приехала))

Comment: @AlexKrass почему сразу медвежья? Например решебники или по английски "How to..." не зря же публикуют. Готовый пример помогает в дальнейших подобных задачах прийти к самостоятельному решению.

Comment: Ну "How to..." и прочие руководства aka tutorial пишутся для тех, у кого достаточно знаний, чтобы в них разобраться самостоятельно и применить на практике. Если знаний недостаточно, к примеру человек не разобравшись еще даже с циклами первый раз увидит LINQ, то увы. Обучение должно быть упорядочено. Он может только бездумно переписать ваш пример и принести преподавателю в надежде, что прокатит. И поплыть, когда начнутся уточняющие вопросы. Толку от этого сами понимаете мало, потому и медвежья.

Comment: В любом случае ваш пример достаточно хорошо сделан, поэтому я только за, если он тут и останется. Именно такими должны быть качественные ответы.

Comment: @AlexKrass да не переживайте, если пример реально поможет человеку - то мы в выигрыше, так как полезность сайта увеличилась. Если не поможет человеку - то мы в выигрыше, меньше будет конкуренция на рынке труда :)